# Can't access to .accdb database when deployed. VB.net / MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, ms-access

this is my first post I am having some trouble with an app, in Visual Studio I can run it on Debug without any issue and everything works correctly, but when I deploy it using IIS I can access any page except of the ones where there is an interaction with an access database. If I search through virtual directory I can download the file without an issue.

Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running x32 or x64 iis? (Usually it x64).

Of course on your desktop, then Visual Studio defaults to x32, and that would explain why the Access database engine (ACE) works. You likely should force your project to x32 or x64 (and then ensure that you have a x64 bit version of the ACE (Access) istalled on your developer machie. You then want to ensure that you launching the x64 bit version of IIS.

You don’t need Access installed on your server, but you will need the ACE database engine – and the most easy way to ensure that data engine is installed is simply installing the Access runtime on that server.

Give that the standard ACE database engine download is x32, then I would look into this issue. You could (should) be able to resolve the issue by installing a x64 bit Access runtime on that server – this would also suggest a possible update to your connection strings.  And I would check/test the connection string you are using once you resolve the x64 bit version of Access. The path name in your connection string will ALWAYS be a absolute path (not a relative one).

Comment: Yes, my computer is running x64 IIS in my understanding but the MS Office that I have is 32 bits I could only install the ACE db engine for x86 I am going to force the application to 32 bits tomorrow and I'll let you know.Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, it was the issue. Thank you!